# JSON file error in Visual Studio Code:Expected comma json(514)

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

A strange problem. I don't think there's something wrong with this **JSON** file,but it tells me: Expected commajsonc(514).
I cannot find any answer to help me out.Though there are many similar answers.
What should I do?

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled",
    "files.associations": {
        "array": "cpp",
        "atomic": "cpp",
        "*.tcc": "cpp",
        "cctype": "cpp",
        "clocale": "cpp",
        "cmath": "cpp",
        "cstdarg": "cpp",
        "cstddef": "cpp",
        "cstdint": "cpp",
        "cstdio": "cpp",
        "cstdlib": "cpp",
        "cwchar": "cpp",
        "cwctype": "cpp",
        "deque": "cpp",
        "unordered_map": "cpp",
        "vector": "cpp",
        "exception": "cpp",
        "algorithm": "cpp",
        "memory": "cpp",
        "memory_resource": "cpp",
        "optional": "cpp",
        "string": "cpp",
        "string_view": "cpp",
        "system_error": "cpp",
        "tuple": "cpp",
        "type_traits": "cpp",
        "utility": "cpp",
        "fstream": "cpp",
        "initializer_list": "cpp",
        "iosfwd": "cpp",
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "istream": "cpp",
        "limits": "cpp",
        "new": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp",
        "stdexcept": "cpp",
        "streambuf": "cpp",
        "typeinfo": "cpp",
    }
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.exe": true,
        "**/*.o": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: （I didn't forget to indent in the real file）

Comment: You can use an online linter to help with issues like this one. Try https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON disallows "trailing commas", a comma after the last value inside a data structure.

Try removing trailing commas on these:

`"typeinfo": "cpp",`

`"**/*.o": true,`

Also, add a comma before this line: `"files.exclude": {`